# Changes ImagenView with a imagen URi Android App

Tags: android

I have one problem in my app: I have a image view preset by a drawable, but when a user presses one button and selects a image for the gallery, I try to change my image using `myImage.setImgenUri("the uri a take previously");` but it crashes all the time.

I searched Google but found nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: Fixed your typos but don't you mean *setImageUri* ?

Comment: of course, sorry for the inconvenience